# How do I set up a website under IIS?

Tags: iis, web-hosting, website

I will start by saying I am not a system admin.  I work as an intern at a construction company doing mostly hardware/software support.

I also publish changes to their website with Dreamweaver.  I was alarmed to see that how I was told to configure Dreamweaver,  it is basically set up to publish directly to the live remote server.

The website is hosted in-house using IIS on Windows Server 2003.

I would like to setup a test site to publish to before pushing new documents to the live website.  I can not simply preview pages in my browser due to the website using sever technology specifically ASP.

I do not want to install IIS on my local machine.  My idea was to create a test site on the same server the actual site exists on.  I basically followed instructions listed here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972 .  I just tried to mirror the settings for the actual site to the test site.  I then took all the files from the directory of the actual site and copied them to the directory of the test site.

I have not been able to get this to work however.  The actual website is configured to be on the internal address 199.5.83.240.  The test site is configured to be on 199.5.83.238.  If you try to access .238 the connection times out.

I thought maybe just some services needed to be restarted.  I have restarted the IIS services and DNS services to no avail.

What am I missing??

Edit:  Additional Info.

The server running IIS is local 199.5.83.229.  There are a couple sites hosted from this IIS server. If I run ipconfig from the server.  It lists .229 as well as .240, .241, .243, .245; but no .238.  I assume this is where my problem lies.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  All I needed to do was Bind an additional IP address to the server running IIS.

I did this by going to TCP/IP configuration > Advanced.  There you can add IP addresses.  I added 199.5.83.238 and I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you could check.

For example, is the public address 199.5.83.238 available from within your network (LAN)? Can you ping that address for example?

Did you set a host header on that web? Check this by clicking the

```
> Website > IP Address > Advanced...
```

button in the properties window of that website. The host header address must be configured in DNS to resolve the the IP address you associated it.

If the default web is active on that server, you could see what happens if you open the internal's server name or ip address in a browser:

```
 http://servername/
```

Normally the default web accepts all IP addresses on that server and all names (host headers) which aren't associated to other websites on the same server.

Comment: I can access http://servername/.  I can access http://199.5.83.240. I did not set a host header because 199.5.83.240 had no host header set.
If I ping 199.5.83.238, I get a response from my local machine's ip address saying the destination host in unreachable.

Comment: Edit for clarity: It turned my http :// servername and http :// ipaddress to a link.